# how to create a web part to track page creation time

Tags: sharepoint-2007, windows-server-2008

I am new to SharePoint Server 2007 Web Part, and I am using SharePoint Server 2007 on Windows Server 2008. I program using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5.

I want to create a simple web part which could display page creation time and modified time (display such time information at the bottom of a web page).

Any reference code samples or tutorials -- anything helpful for a newbie of SharePoint 2007 Web Part or this specific time tracking issue is helpful.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: This really belongs on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Developing for SharePoint is a big leap - for example, the official scenario is doing your development directly on a server.  So most SP devs end up building a virtual machine for their development.

[Creating an SP dev environment.](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2006/02/09/437788.aspx)

[Creating a custom web part for SP2007.](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/webforms/article.php/c12293/)

Personally, I use the VSeWSS add-in ([version 1.3, March CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FB9D4B85-DA2A-432E-91FB-D505199C49F6)) for developing sharepoint "solutions" (really, cab files that wrap up functionality) that contain "features."  Many devs prefer other tools, such as STSDEV or WSPBuilder.

Once you get that far creating the web part you need should be simple.

Comment: see this "getting started in SP" question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110341/getting-started-developing-for-sharepoint